# To isolate static methods into a module ? Possible ? "undefined method"

Tags: ruby

I try to understand module...

I would like to isolate many methods in one module (to access to them just with Namemodule.methodname )

Here my code :

## domparser.rb

```
module Domparser

   def method1 name
   
      puts "Ok : method1" + name
   
   end
   
    def method2
   
      method1("John")
      puts "Ok : method2 without name"
   
   end

    def method3
   
      method2
      puts "Ok : MAIN METHOD"
   
   end

end
```

## main.rb

```
require("./domparser.rb")

Domparser.method3
```

But => `undefined method 'method3' for Domdecoder:Module (NoMethodError)`

I have other methods called "method1" and "method2", it's why I would like to isolate them into a module.

And `method3` is the only method that I want to call outside.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `module_function` for the methods that you would like to access directly on the module

```
module Domparser
   def method1 name
      puts "Ok : method1" + name
   end

    def method2
      method1("John")
      puts "Ok : method2 without name"
   end

    def method3
      method2
      puts "Ok : MAIN METHOD"
   end

   module_function :method3
end
```

Now you can access method3 on module as well as a instance method on the class you include this module on

```
Domparser.method3
```

More information about module_function [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried 5minutes ago but : `in 'method3': undefined method 'method2' for Domparser:Module (NoMethodError)`  Indeed, method3 calls method2 etc...    I only want to call method3 and when every called methods into method3, are called into the module.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I put every methods into a class and I have `self.` in front of method name.

```
class Domparser

   def self.method1 name

      puts "Ok : method1" + name

   end

    def self.method2

      method1("John")
      puts "Ok : method2 without name"

   end

    def self.method3

      method2
      puts "Ok : MAIN METHOD"

   end

end
```

And it works.

`Domparser.method3`

Comment: I would want to have another way to do this without changing anything. (if I had had many more of methods...)